# I'm trying to include ng-swicth inside ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a menu to navigate through my data model:

```
            <div class="nav">
                <span us-spinner ng-if="vm.dataReady == false"></span>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li ng-repeat="section in vm.data"
                        ng-class="{'active':vm.activePersonalDataTab == $index}"
                        ng-click="vm.personalDataTabClick($index)">
                        {{section.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Data is a simple object like this one:

```
personalData: [
                { name: "Общие сведения", src: "CommonInfo/GetCommonInfo", dataType: 0, data: null },
                { name: "Биография", src: null, subNames: [
                        { name: "Сведения об образовании", src: "EducationInfo/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                        { name: "Сведения о службе в вооруженных силах", src: "MilitaryServiceInfo/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                        { name: "Сведения о семейном положении", src: "FamilyInfo/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                        { name: "Сведения о судимости", src: "ConvictionInfo/Read", dataType: 1, data: null }          
                ]},
                { name: "Занимаемые должности", src: "PersonPosition/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                { name: "Поощрения и взыскания", src: "PromotionRecovery/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                { name: "Публикации в СМИ", src: "PublicationInfo/Read", dataType: 1, data: null },
                { name: "Сведения о смерти", src: "DeathInfo/GetDeathInfo", dataType: 0, data: null }
            ], //dataType: 0 - list, 1 - table
```

Where 'src' is a name of API controllers. My service using them to get data and then write it in the 'data' property.  Now I'm trying to use **ng-repeat** to loop through all data items and **ng-switch** to check if it'a one that is selected in my menu (selected menu index is stored in vm.activePersonalDataTab):

```
<div ng-repeat="section in vm.data" ng-init="sectionIndex=$index" ng-switch="vm.activePersonalDataTab">
<div ng-switch-when="{{sectionIndex}}" ng-switch="vm.data[sectionIndex].dataType">
    <div ng-switch-when="0" class="info">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in vm.dict[sectionIndex]" class="{{vm.getLiClass($index)}}"
                ng-init="field = vm.getFieldValue(sectionIndex,$index)">
                <div class="my-label">{{vm.getFieldName(sectionIndex,$index)}}&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="my-info">{{field.type === 1 ? (field.value | date:'dd.MM.yyyy') : field.value}}&nbsp;</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--Если данные представлены простым списком-->
    <div ng-switch-when="1" class="table"></div>not yeat<!--Если данные представлены таблицей-->
    <div ng-switch-default class="bunch">not yeat</div><!--Если данные представлены набором таблиц-->

</div>
```

It's works if I change **{{sectionIndex}}** to **0** in *ng-switch-when="{{sectionIndex}}*. Byt I whant to use index from ng-repeat for automate this part of my code.

Comment: sounds like you need to `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` and use that

Comment: I tryed,  no effect.

Comment: ng-switch-when does not accept expression.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566118/angular-js-ng-switch-when-not-working-with-dynamic-data

Comment: looks like a good candidate for a custom directive or components